# MSB6003: The specified task executable "CL.exe" could not be run

Tags: c, vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I have been getting this error in my VisualBasic 2017 console since last night, for no apparent reason. I have been coding and compiling the same code for a while now and it hasn't give me any issues. I tried looking for this specific error, but could not find anywhere. The whole text of the error was:

MSB6003: The specified task executable "CL.exe" could not be run. The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary solution to this issue, I moved my project folder (all the *.c and *.h and vcxproj and all these files to a folder directly under a drive name, such as E:\VB_project and now its compiling fine again.

I didnot change anything to the directory at all but it just started happening. Hope it helps others as well, and I hope someone can give me a logical reason why this happened.
Thanks!

Comment: The path to one (or multiple) of your project's files was too long. A complete path (for example `C:\some\path\to\some\file.exe`) can only be (like the error says) 260 characters long. By moving your project from a deeper directory tree to the root of the `E:\ ` drive the path to your project files becomes much shorter, thus the problem is solved. It is not a temporary solution, it is _**the**_ solution.

Comment: See this for more information: [**Maximum Path Length Limitation - Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces (MSDN)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#maxpath)

Comment: Thanks for that @Visual Vincent. How come it was working just fine a while ago and then suddenly it started happening? Oh wait, I think I know why, VB was making backups of my files and it was naming each file with the file name and then date and time stamp to avoid versioning problems. That might be a reason. Do you think so?

Comment: New files or directories in a too deep tree or with too long names is the issue here, yes. That backup feature could be a cause as it makes the file name longer, but only if the project accesses the file somehow. Another reason could be that you've added a file or directory (or both) in a too deep directory tree that caused the full path to it to become longer than 260 chars.